# how to mask email/mobile_number if existed in a string column using talend , either by java or using expression builder in Tmap

Tags: talend

I'm very new to Talend and I have a user commented text column where a sample record like

```
my email_id is example@gmail.com and mobile_number is 9998887776
```

Now my requirement is to mask the email and mobile_number in such a way that email should be

```
e******@gmail.com
```

and mobile_number should be

```
#######776
```

i.e. if both `email_id` and `mobile_number` exists in the column , how can I achieve this.

I have tried using the expression builder with string handling functions. 
Can anyone explain me briefly.

Comment: can you show us your code what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

There's no predefined method to do this. You can create your own "routine" with methods that you can call in the talend components (e.g. in the expression editor of a tMap). A routine is basically just a Java class with static methods. You can find [an example here.](https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-code-routines-reference.html)

With Java you have access to a lot of tools to help you with your task. I'd use [Pattern Matching](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) to find the email address and mobile number via RegEx then mask those values, but that's just one way to do it.